# Is a block without transactions valid: also not including a coinbase?

Tags: block, coinbase-transaction, empty-blocks

We know blocks can have *one* transaction: the coinbase.
Some call this an "empty block". But I'd argue technically there is a transaction.

Question: is a block WITHOUT A COINBASE a valid block?

The merkle root would be calculated on NULL so I am guessing no [?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consensus rules require a block to have at least one transaction. It also requires transactions to have at least one input and at least one output.